# multiple reverse SSH tunnel with same port on same server

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ssh, port-forwarding, openssh

I'm looking for a solution for connecting to multiple remote computers through reverse SSH tunnels from one computer/software on the same port.

I have **remote1** and **remote2** where I cannot open network ports, so I setup reverse tunnels for each one, with a specific port, connecting though my home SSH server (rpi3). so i.e. I'm connecting trough ssh from my local computer to my server (rpi3), on specific ports depending on remote1 or remote2. this works perfectly, when it's only about connecting from software where I can specify connection port.

but what are my option if the soft I'd like to connect from application that have no option for specifying port? I'd like to connect to port **8080**, sometimes to **remote1**, and sometimes to **remote2**.

I've explored the Virtual IP option, but I understand that rpi makes no real difference between connection to eth0, or eth0:0. I thought I could maybe route somehow connections from eth0:0 to specific a port, but it doesn't look like an option.

my local machine where I'm running the soft connecting to 8080 is macOs. is there any option for routing traffic from a specific application to a specific port, temporarily? so I could make a rule where any connection from my macOs to port 8080 would route to 8081?

or is there any option on the rpi?
would creating multiple TUN help? or any other interface?

Comment: You can create virtual IP's and assign the same port to different IP's.    
If your connections are http/https then you can use proxy capable software like nginx to do a proxy_pass depending on the URL given.

Personally I use avahi mdns hostnames and nginx virtual hosts to map between local to remote addresses.  Very simple and you get to chose the hostnames.  e.g. metrics.local, homebridge.local etc.    Much easier to remember than port numbers MIHO

Comment: would this work with IP addresses only? my soft only deals with IPs and no hostname. I will dig into nginx virtual hosts, thank you!

Comment: virtual hosts are same IP address  but the HTTP request itself supplies a unique server name which allows the underlying software to redirect differently.

IP based where there is one unique IP address is similar to using unique ports..  Just remember to bind your ports to the unique IP addresses and not the 0.0.0.0 which binds the port to all IP's available on the box including localhost (127.0.0.1).

Its a good little project to ramp up on as you'll learn a lot about IP/ports and virtual hosts :-)

Comment: For nginx..  https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/create-manage-virtual-hosts-nginx/

Comment: An example from my home server.. I have a monitor.local MDNS name advertised to the entire network called 'monitor.local'  on my home server I have a nginx entry..

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name monitor.local;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8666;
    }
}


So that binds to port 80 on the home servers ip addresses..  When a request comes in it redirects the request to http://localhost:8666.  Simples..

However whilst available works out of the box with linux and macOS.. Windows isn't quite so helpful..  Worth looking into for linux on its own IMHO..

Comment: I think I understand the idea of nginx and mDNS with hostnames, redirecting to various ports on localhost. but I'm not sure how I could do that if my only way to make request from my client to my server is through IP (as my application only accepts IP entry), and not hostname. from what I understood, your example works with hostname (monitor.local) and this hostname will be redirected to a specific port at localhost, thanks to ngnix. but how can I do if I can't use hostname? could nginx also redirect virtual IPs requests?